# Check if substring is in a string as a individual word

Tags: python, json, string

I am trying to create a voice assistant with Python. For many commands I use trigger words like "exit", "time", "quit" etc.

But since it keeps track of the voice, sometimes it picks up voice it shouldn't, like for the word "sen**time**ntal" it tells me the time. I have used word barriers (`\\b`), but I want singular words to work as well.

So "I acquitted him" wouldn't close the program. But "quit" or "please quit" would.

This is my current json setup:

```json
{
    "BasicOperations": {
        "goodbye": ["'bye", "exit", "quit", "see you"],
        "time": ["time ", "getting late"],
        "calculations": ["+", "-", "*", "/", "^"]
    }

}
```

And this is the code for checking:

```py
    # Tell the time
    if any(string in query for string in commands["time"]):
        engine.say('The time is ' + time)
        engine.runAndWait()
    
    # Quit the program
    elif any(string in query for string in commands["goodbye"]):
        engine.say("Good night sir! Have a nice sleep." if is_night else "Bye sir, have a great day!" )
        engine.runAndWait()
        exit()
    
    elif any(string in query for string in commands["calculations"]):
        #op1, op2 = int(op1), int(op2)

        for op in commands["calculations"]:
            if (op in query):
                print(op)

        #answer =  get_operator_fn()(op1, op2)
        engine.say("Good night sir! Have a nice sleep." if is_night else "Bye sir, have a great day!" )
        engine.runAndWait()
        exit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a function which can be called in the for loop condition, which will have checks for the following:

- If the string is the first word in the query or the letter in the previous index is a space
- If the string is the last word in the query or the letter in the next index is a space

If both these conditions are true, return True else return False.

```
def present(string, query):
    ind = query.find(string)
    if ind != -1:
        if ind==0 or (ind>0 and query[ind-1]==' '):
            if ind+len(string)==len(query) or (query[ind+len(string)]==' '):
                return True
    return False

#Tell the time
    if any(present(string, query) for string in commands["time"]):
        engine.say('The time is ' + time)
        engine.runAndWait()
    
    # Quit the program
    elif any(present(string, query) for string in commands["goodbye"]):
        engine.say("Good night sir! Have a nice sleep." if is_night else "Bye sir, have a great day!" )
        engine.runAndWait()
        exit()
    
    elif any(present(string, query) for string in commands["calculations"]):
        #op1, op2 = int(op1), int(op2)

        for op in commands["calculations"]:
            if (op in query):
                print(op)

        #answer =  get_operator_fn()(op1, op2)
        engine.say("Good night sir! Have a nice sleep." if is_night else "Bye sir, have a great day!" )
        engine.runAndWait()
        exit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `re.search` with starting and ending anchors:

```py
# Tell the time
regex = r'^(?:' + r'|'.join(re.escape(x) for x in commands["time"]) + r')$'
if re.search(regex, query):
    engine.say('The time is ' + time)
    engine.runAndWait()

# Quit the program
regex = r'^(?:' + r'|'.join(re.escape(x) for x in commands["goodbye"]) + r')$'
elif re.search(regex, query):
    engine.say("Good night sir! Have a nice sleep." if is_night else "Bye sir, have a great day!" )
    engine.runAndWait()
    exit()

regex = r'^(?:' + r'|'.join(re.escape(x) for x in commands["calculations"]) + r')$'
elif re.search(regex, query):
    #op1, op2 = int(op1), int(op2)

    for op in commands["calculations"]:
        if (op in query):
            print(op)

    #answer =  get_operator_fn()(op1, op2)
    engine.say("Good night sir! Have a nice sleep." if is_night else "Bye sir, have a great day!" )
    engine.runAndWait()
    exit()
```